# Laravel foreach in method returning only last result

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, jasper-reports

I've searched a lot about this with no result. Sorry if it's duplicated but I have a issue using JasperPHP in laravel 5.2 and I need a help.

I'm trying to generate a report (obviously) and I'm using a method with a foreach to get a list for the report.

```
$results = $this->PessoaRepository->all();
$nomeCompleto = '';
$cpf = '';
foreach($results as $pessoa){
    $nomeCompleto = $pessoa['nome_completo'];
    $cpf = $pessoa['cpf'];
}

$jasper = new JasperPHP();

$jasper->process(
    app_path() . "/Domains/Pessoas/Reports/Pessoa/Pessoas.jrxml",
    false,
    array('pdf', 'rtf', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'docx', 'odt', 'ods', 'pptx', 'csv', 'html', 'xhtml', 'xml', 'jrprint'),
    array('nome_completo' => $nomeCompleto, 'cpf' => $cpf)
    **strong text**)->execute();
```

When I call this method everything works, it generate the files but the foreach is returning only the last result. How could I solve it or pass a list to jasperPHP generate it?

Comment: You are storing in a variable, so it will store the last result. Maybe you need to store it as an array or a concatenated string.

Comment: You're overwriting the variables mate.

Comment: @SalvadorP. you're the first person with the right answer, so maybe add it below so the OP can accept?

Comment: Posted as an answer, thank you for the hint. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the value.

Maybe this will work for you, or try something different, use arrays or something.

```
$results = $this->PessoaRepository->all();
$nomeCompleto = '';
$cpf = '';
foreach($results as $pessoa){
    $nomeCompleto .= $pessoa['nome_completo'].' '; // not overwrite the var
    $cpf .= $pessoa['cpf'].' ';
}

$jasper = new JasperPHP();

$jasper->process(
    app_path() . "/Domains/Pessoas/Reports/Pessoa/Pessoas.jrxml",
    false,
    array('pdf', 'rtf', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'docx', 'odt', 'ods', 'pptx', 'csv', 'html', 'xhtml', 'xml', 'jrprint'),
    array('nome_completo' => $nomeCompleto, 'cpf' => $cpf)
    **strong text**)->execute();
```

Comment: Yeah, in fact now I can get all the objects in the same line. I'll try something different, but at least this is one solution. Thanks